# how to prevent loading a php file in wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a php file inside a plugin folder and it makes problem in the admin area media uploader. how to prevent that file from being loaded inside admin area?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to not load a specific file. The only thing that you can do is going through the code and commenting the code out that uses/loads the file.